# Login con Ajax, PHP y MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

Tengo una duda, estoy empezando a trabajar con Ajax y PHP y quiero saber como puedo hacer un login con Ajax para que valide el usuario si esta registrado o no, mis usuarios los tengo en una base de datos en MySQL pero no se como hacer esa validacion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El proceso de login de cualquier sitio, no es trivial. Se puede hacer fácilmente con un simple acceso a la web, pero si quieres algo seguro, no es recomendable hacer cosas como ...

> SELECT * FROM USUARIOS WHERE usuario = $parametroUsuario and clave = $parametroClave

Debes tener cuidado con el [sql injection](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp) y otros problemas

Te recomiendo seguir este ejemplo que se basa en el uso de sesiones. Para empezar, y en cuanto a relación dificultad/seguridad, está muy bien

http://www.codingcage.com/2015/11/ajax-login-script-with-jquery-php-mysql.html

Comment: Muchas gracias, lo voy a revisar y poner en practica

Answer (score 3):

La consulta a la base de datos debe ser algo parecido a esto:

```
SELECT * FROM USUARIOS WHERE usuario = $parametroUsuario and clave = $parametroClave
```

Si la clave ha sido cifrada, por ejemplo, con md5, y al no saber que motor de base de datos estás usando recomiendo que generes la clave a nivel de PHP. Algo como lo siguiente:

```
$encriptClave = md5($parametroClave)
```

La consulta SQL te puede retornar información. Si retorna información significa que el usuario existe, caso contrario, no lo hace. Esta consulta obviamente tiene que estar definida dentro de un método en PHP para que puedas utilizarla, y que retorne por ejemplo, OK si el acceso es correcto, o FAIL si no existe el usuario. Hay otras maneras, como indicar errores HTTP, etc, pero sería complicar el ejercicio.

En ajax tu tienes que indicar en que URL se encuentra tu método de validación, ejemplo:

```
mysite.com/auth.php?action=login
```

Y a esa URL le vas a enviar el usuario y clave que introdujo el usuario, por lo general a través del método POST. Ajax retornará información, si el mensaje es OK significa que el acceso es correcto, sino, será una autenticación fallida.

Te recomiendo encarecidamente revisar algún tutorial en Youtube donde se abarquen todas estas cuestiones ya que hay conceptos básicos que debes aprender para que sigas mejorando en tus proyectos.